# 'Change Color' button Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a drawing app. I define the color of lines (red by default) using Kivy Canvas and the task is I need a button for example 'Green' that will change the color to green. I don't know actually understand how to do it.

What I tried is:

```
class PainterWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        with self.canvas:
            self.color = Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            rad = 30
            Ellipse(pos = (touch.x, touch.y), size = (rad / 2, rad / 2))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y), width = 15)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += touch.x, touch.y

    def blue(self):

        with self.canvas:
            self.color = Color(0, 0, 1, 1)

class PaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = PainterWidget()
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)

        parent.add_widget(Button(text='Blue', size=(50, 50), pos=(0, 480), on_press = PainterWidget.blue))


        return parent
```

But it doesn't work. I tried creating the color changing method in PaintApp doing something like PainterWidget.color = Color but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

Add a ListProperty, `paint_color` and assigned the default red color. When the Button is pressed change paint_color from red to blue. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.properties import ListProperty


class PainterWidget(Widget):
    paint_color = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=self.paint_color)
            rad = 30
            Ellipse(pos = (touch.x, touch.y), size = (rad / 2, rad / 2))
            touch.ud['line'] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y), width = 15)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += touch.x, touch.y

    def blue(self, instance):
        self.paint_color = [0, 0, 1, 1]


class PaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = PainterWidget()
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)

        parent.add_widget(Button(text='Blue', size=(50, 50), pos=(0, 480), on_press=self.painter.blue))

        return parent


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PaintApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Red and Blue colors]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I did it and it still doesn't change the color

Comment: Add a `ListProperty` called `paint_color` and updates it from red to blue color. Please refer to updated post.